# How to check Drush version?

Tags: drush

How can I identify what version of Drush is installed on a given system?

Comment: Many of your very specific Drush questions could be easily answered by reading, or even skimming, the [Drush documentation](http://drush.ws).

Comment: What Tim said. We really need to avoid the trivial questions during private beta.

Comment: I totally understand the need to avoid certain types of questions. I would argue that just because a question is what some might consider 'trivial' doesn't make it a bad question. Vague, open-ended, chatty, subjective; these are the types of questions we should strive to avoid. If we are serious about this site as the go-to place for answers to Drupal questions these are exactly the types of questions people will come here looking for the answer to. Just my two cents!

Comment: even if they can be "easily answered by reading, or even skimming, the xxx documentation" ?

Comment: [Drush docs](www.drush.ws) have a glossary of all commands and options and it takes about 10 seconds to find what you need.

Comment: Mark is right. This is a relevant question. My hosting company installed drush for me ni the webserver and I needed to check the version. Turns out the "normal" drush --version didn't work because they installed an ancient Drush 3. I'm glad I found the answer here.

Comment: www.drush.ws is a github repository. Good luck finding *anything* there.

Comment: I disagree with Tim. It is way easier to find information on google when there is a question associated with what you are looking for.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming you have Drush installed and working properly, just type `drush status` in your command prompt. It will give you drush version as well as Drupal version info. If you have aliases set up for remote (or local) sites, you can run `drush @alias status` and it will give you the status info for that remote system.

Comment: Since Drush 4.2 : `drush version`
This is a good way to know if drush is installed and running.

Answer (score 21):

`drush --version` works in Drush 4 too.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `drush st` as a shortcut (alias) for `drush status`

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If your Drush installation is not working and you have an older version of drush, then neither `drush status` nor `drush --version` will help. In that case go to the directory where drush is installed (~/.drush/drush on my system) and look at the drush.info file. There you will see a line that says `version=3.0` (or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

You can check Drush version with "drush status" command inside your application directory or outside your application directory, the difference will be when you are inside application directory you will get more information,

Check below links for better understanding on Drush commands,

http://mydons.com/commonly-used-drush-commands-drupal-developers-must-know/
http://mydons.com/install-and-upgrade-drush-version-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

```
drush --version
```

Works for Drush 8 and Drush 7 too.

You can also see the other global options by

```
drush topic core-global-options
```